# Sharp returning errors on npm install for M1 Big Sur

Tags: npm, gulp, homebrew, sharp

I'm trying to install sharp for my project. When running npm i and npm install sharp, I am receiving the same errors about sharp (shown below). I've tried installing libvip globally and locally, and read about every thread about this issue and cannot seem to find the right solution. Any suggestions are welcome.

```html
rosetta error: /var/db/oah/223263137464320_223263137464320/e6ddd63cd8fd3b7ef226e2cad9a1bead9d7f41f60d7ece6edd0cdcc0c33c97c6/libxcrun.dylib.aot: attachment of code signature supplement failed: 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: null
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/elektra.murphy/.nvm/versions/node/v11.11.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:197:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:254:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/elektra.murphy/.nvm/versions/node/v11.11.0/bin/node" "/Users/elektra.murphy/.nvm/versions/node/v11.11.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/elektra.murphy/Desktop/Projects/node_modules/sharp
gyp ERR! node -v v11.11.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/elektra.murphy/Desktop/Projects/package.json'
npm WARN No description
npm WARN No repository field.
npm WARN No README data
npm WARN No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sharp@0.23.2 install: `(node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the sharp@0.23.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/elektra.murphy/.npm/_logs/2021-10-12T08_24_48_579Z-debug.log
```

Comment: What does the fox say? I mean What does the log say?

Comment: This is the error I've been trying to solve: npm ERR! sharp@0.23.2 install: `(node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)`
npm ERR! Exit status 1

Comment: If you open `/Users/elektra.murphy/.npm/_logs/2021-10-12T08_24_48_579Z-debug.log`, there should be more info about the problem

Comment: Found a solution for this in the Sharp docs: When using npm v6 or earlier, the npm install --unsafe-perm flag must be used when installing as root or a sudo user. Seems to have worked - now on to the next error!

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for this in the Sharp docs: When using npm v6 or earlier, the npm install --unsafe-perm flag must be used when installing as root or a sudo user. Seems to have worked - now on to the next error!

Find more here on M1 installations:

https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install